# intersection of circle and lines ? $1$

Tags: geometry

what is the number of points in intersection,in $\mathbb{R^2}$ of the two plane curves $(1+x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2-4)=0 $   and  $  y=7x $?

As I was visualising the diagram ,[image]

from the diagram i can conclude that,,,number of points intersection $\mathbb{R^2}$ is $0$ as there is no intersection points.....

Please! verify my mistake where am I wrong?

Comment: The line $y=7x$ does not pass through $(0,7)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1+x^2+y^2=0$

$x^2+y^2=-1$

So it has no solutions (even when you substitute $y=7x$).

$x^2+y^2=4$

Has solutions. Substitute $y=7x$

$50x^2= 4$

$x^2=\frac{2}{25}$

So they intersect at two points, whose $x$ value is either $\sqrt{\frac{2}{25}}$ or $-\sqrt{\frac{2}{25}}$

To find $y$ of the points, substitute $x^2+y^2=4$: $\sqrt{\frac{2}{25}}$ and $-\sqrt{\frac{2}{25}}$

Comment: thanks a lots@ MCCS

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

your figure is wrong. I am not able to comment the figure.[image: enter image [![enter image description here]

Comment: thanks a lots Maneesh